# How to use prime31 in app billing plugin Unity android to add action on purchase

Tags: unity-game-engine, prime31

I have a big problem.
I got the plugin to work, and i can test purchase my items.
But i can`t find the place in the scripts where i can add the action to use when a item was purchased. i have 3 items, named "item60" "item70" and "item80".
Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

i use prime31 and i take care of the actions in this method, here is my remove ads purchase

```
    void purchaseSucceededEvent( GooglePurchase purchase )
        {
            Debug.Log( "purchaseSucceededEvent: " + purchase );

            if(purchase.purchaseState == GooglePurchase.GooglePurchaseState.Purchased){
            if(purchase.productId == "jacs.apps.adds")
                {
                    Debug.Log("inside jacs.apps.adds");
                    if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("plus"))
                        {
                        adds = false;
                            PlayerPrefs.SetString("addskey","true");



                        }else{
                        PlayerPrefs.SetString("plus","on");

                        adds = false;
                            PlayerPrefs.SetString("addskey","true");

                                }

                    GoogleIAB.consumeProduct( "jacs.apps.adds" );
                }
    }
}
```